Lazarus/FreePascal LibreOffice automation events
I am trying to write an app in Lazarus (Windows) which uses LibreOffice (Calc) automation to edit spreadsheets and responds to modification and save events.
I had a working version of this in Delphi, but I can't port the code directly, as FreePascal does not seem to have any implementations of the IConnectionPoint and IConnectionPoints interfaces.
I can successfully open and manipulate documents using the standard CreateOleObject function to get the top-level object:
var libreMgr, libreDsk: OleVariant;

libreMgr := CreateOleObject('com.sun.star.ServiceManager');
libreDsk := libreMgr.createInstance('com.sun.star.frame.Desktop'); 

etc...

But I can't figure out how to create and connect an event interface.
My Delphi implementation (from many years ago) involved overriding the Delphi TComServer to load the LibreOffice type library without adding it to the registry, I've lost the original attribution for this, but I certainly did not figure it out from scratch by myself!
Here's my original Delphi unit - this does not compile in Lazarus because of the TConnectionPoints type - I tried re-implementing this class, but it just does nothing at runtime - the app runs, but no events are received.
interface

uses
  ComObj, Windows, ActiveX, AxCtrls, Classes, LibreOfficeEventListener_TLB;

type
  TLibreEvent = procedure(const Source: OleVariant) of object;

  ILibreOfficeEvents = interface(IDispatch)
    ['{06E57844-1345-406B-A18B-C7D88C44F11E}']
    // additional events can be added here if required, this interface
    // does not need to be immutable
    function Get_OnUnload: TLibreEvent;
    procedure Set_OnUnload(Value: TLibreEvent);
     function Get_OnModifyChanged: TLibreEvent;
    procedure Set_OnModifyChanged(Value: TLibreEvent);
    function Get_OnPrepareUnload: TLibreEvent;
    procedure Set_OnPrepareUnload(Value: TLibreEvent);
    property OnUnload: TLibreEvent read Get_OnUnload write Set_OnUnload;
    property OnModifyChanged: TLibreEvent read Get_OnModifyChanged write Set_OnModifyChanged;
     property OnPrepareUnload: TLibreEvent read Get_OnPrepareUnload write Set_OnPrepareUnload;
  end;

  // To connect to LibreOffice document events, we have to implement an
  // IDispatch listener with a type library, but it does not need to be registered.
  // This is an acceptable compromise - it is not a full-blown COM object,
  // but the type-library must be included as a resource in the EXE.
  TLibreOfficeEventListener = class(TAutoObject,
    IConnectionPointContainer,
    ILibreOfficeEventListener,
    ILibreOfficeEvents)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FConnectionPoints: TConnectionPoints;
    FConnectionPoint: TConnectionPoint;
    FEvents: ILibreOfficeEventListenerEvents;
    { note: FEvents maintains a *single* event sink. For access to more
      than one event sink, use FConnectionPoint.SinkList, and iterate
      through the list of sinks. }
    FOnUnload: TLibreEvent;
    FOnModifyChanged: TLibreEvent;
    FOnPrepareUnload: TLibreEvent;
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
    property ConnectionPoints: TConnectionPoints read FConnectionPoints implements IConnectionPointContainer;
    procedure EventSinkChanged(const EventSink: IUnknown); override;
    { ILibreOfficeEventListener methods }
    procedure disposing; safecall;
    procedure notifyEvent(const event: IDispatch); safecall;
    { ILibreOfficeEvents methods }
    function Get_OnUnload: TLibreEvent;
    procedure Set_OnUnload(Value: TLibreEvent);
     function Get_OnModifyChanged: TLibreEvent;
    procedure Set_OnModifyChanged(Value: TLibreEvent);
    function Get_OnPrepareUnload: TLibreEvent;
    procedure Set_OnPrepareUnload(Value: TLibreEvent);
  public
    procedure Initialize; override;
  end;

{$R LibreOfficeEventListener.TLB} // type library is REQUIRED for hooking LibreOffice events

implementation

uses ComServNoRegister;

type
  TAutoObjectFactoryNoRegister = class(TAutoObjectFactory)
  public
    procedure UpdateRegistry(Register: Boolean); override;
  end;

procedure TLibreOfficeEventListener.EventSinkChanged(const EventSink: IUnknown);
begin
  FEvents := EventSink as ILibreOfficeEventListenerEvents;
end;

procedure TLibreOfficeEventListener.Initialize;
begin
  inherited Initialize;
  FConnectionPoints := TConnectionPoints.Create(Self);
  if AutoFactory.EventTypeInfo <> nil then
    FConnectionPoint := FConnectionPoints.CreateConnectionPoint(
      AutoFactory.EventIID, ckSingle, EventConnect)
  else FConnectionPoint := nil;
end;


procedure TLibreOfficeEventListener.disposing;
begin
   // do nothing here
end;

procedure TLibreOfficeEventListener.notifyEvent(const event: IDispatch);
var
    e: OleVariant;
begin
    e := event;
   { document events which can be intercepted:
     OnTitleChanged
     OnModifyChanged
     OnStorageChanged
     OnModeChanged
     OnSave
     OnSaveDone
     OnSaveAs
     OnSaveAsDone
     OnPrepareUnload
     OnUnload
   }
   if e.EventName='OnModifyChanged' then begin
    if Assigned(FOnModifyChanged) then FOnModifyChanged(e.Source);
   end
   else if e.EventName='OnPrepareUnload' then begin // CM 12/09/2024 added
    if Assigned(FOnPrepareUnload) then FOnPrepareUnload(e.Source);
   end
   else if e.EventName='OnUnload' then begin
    if Assigned(FOnUnload) then FOnUnload(e.Source);
   end;
end;

function TLibreOfficeEventListener.Get_OnUnload: TLibreEvent;
begin
   Result := FOnUnload;
end;

procedure TLibreOfficeEventListener.Set_OnUnload(Value: TLibreEvent);
begin
   FOnUnload := Value;
end;

{ TAutoObjectFactoryNoRegister }

procedure TAutoObjectFactoryNoRegister.UpdateRegistry(Register: Boolean);
begin
   // do nothing - do not save COM class or typelib info in the registry.
   // See also ComServNoRegister.pas
end;

function TLibreOfficeEventListener.Get_OnModifyChanged: TLibreEvent;
begin
   Result := FOnModifyChanged;
end;

procedure TLibreOfficeEventListener.Set_OnModifyChanged(Value: TLibreEvent);
begin
   FOnModifyChanged := Value;
end;

function TLibreOfficeEventListener.Get_OnPrepareUnload: TLibreEvent;
begin
    Result := FOnPrepareUnload;
end;

procedure TLibreOfficeEventListener.Set_OnPrepareUnload(Value: TLibreEvent);
begin
    FOnPrepareUnload := Value;
end;

initialization
  TAutoObjectFactoryNoRegister.Create(ComServer, TLibreOfficeEventListener,
    Class_LibreOfficeEventListener, ciMultiInstance, tmApartment);
end.

This should be hooked to the open LO doc by calling
libreDoc.addEventListener(libreEvents);

But, as I said, this does nothing.
Any help, or pointers to other implementations would be a great help, thanks!
Has anyone done this before?

Try posting on ask.libreoffice.org — I believe user Lupp has a good understanding of Delphi at least. In Python, you can create a class that listens and then add it to the document, as explained at https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/sbasic/python/python_document_events.html.

Thanks Jim, yes the python sample is similar in concept to the delphi unit I included in my question. It just seems that Lazarus/FreePascal is missing some of the low-level plumbing objects that make this work. I will post to ask.libreoffice.org anyway, to see if I get any answers there.

Your definition of TLibreEvent is a double pointer (one for the method address, one for the SELF/THIS), and it is used in the COM interface. It is highly unlikely that libreoffice supports this kind of Delphi internal style events.
I also miss any calling convention modifiers in your interface definition.
You could try to post a sample project at the lazarus forum, and in general C/C++ examples are better suited than Python (since you never know what the interpreter and/or packages shield under the hood)

The ILibreOfficeEvents interface defined in my unit above is not used by libreoffice, this is purely an internal interface used within my app, so calling conventions are not needed. The actual event interface used by LO appears to be the IConnectionPoints, and this is what I am having trouble implementing. I'll try asking on the lazarus form too

Please do. If I have something to test I will test too. Please also state 32 or 64-bit.

I've posted a question on the lazarus forum too - https://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,68806.0.html

No help so far from the lazarus forum so far. Surely I can't be the only person trying to hook LibreOffice events...?
